# PHP mySQL RLIKE similar expanded + or - 5

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Using RLIKE I am able to find people with similar surnames or telephone numbers.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE (surname RLIKE '$surname' OR telephone RLIKE '$telephone') LIMIT 9");
```

1 - Problem is I need it to priorities to surnames and then go for telephone numbers second up to a total limit of 9 records.

2 - Also want to concatenate the first line of address `address1` and the `postcode` to find similar records

This way if the house number was say 14 and the postcode ZZ18MP then it would find nearby houses. eg. 12 ZZ18MP. Most households aren't in the system so it can't increment by 1, it needs to be a closest match.

How do we do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [full text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) and get the ranks for suranmes and telephone numbers. based on that rank, filter our the data.

Here is a tutorial to start
http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

**Note**: The Full-text searches are supported for MyISAM tables only